# jQuery Window Scroll code formatting issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

*newbie: writing jQuery on my own*

So I'm running into a snag with having jQuery add a class once the window has scrolled down after a set amount of pixels.

To set a little background, the navbar currently has some jQuery that toggles classes to create a little fade effect when clicked. It's static and sits down a little ways on the page. My problem is adding the jQuery that continues to add classes as the window is scrolled down to basically add the class that will make the navbar fixed to the top of the page once the static nav is out of view.

I'm creating a child theme with a custom .js functions file - here is the code that works so far:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
    $('.testimonials').bxSlider();

   $('.home .siteBrand').click(function(){
        $('.home .x-navbar').toggleClass("x-navbarOpen");
        $('.home .x-navbar').addClass("ani");
        $('.home .x-nav-wrap.desktop').toggleClass("siteBrandOpen");
        $('.home .x-nav-wrap.desktop').addClass("ani");
        $('.home .x-navbar .desktop .x-nav > li > a').toggleClass("menuOpen");
        $('.home .x-navbar .desktop .x-nav > li > a').addClass("ani");

    });
});
```

The following code is what worked from another site:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();   

$j(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $j(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 750) {
        $j(".home .x-navbar").addClass("x-navbar-fixed-top");
    } else {
        $j(".home .x-navbar").removeClass("x-navbar-fixed-top");
    }
});
```

It only works when adding the code to the Custom Javascript feature of the theme, but I need this to all be in the child theme's custom .js file and after much playing with the code, I'm not sure how to format this snippet to make it work within the custom file. One of the issues I noticed is regardless if I add the window scroll code in the theme feature or try to play around with it in the custom file, the code that did work in the custom file stops.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to comment out ...

```
//var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

... and replace every reference from `$j` to `$`.

The "other site" probably had 2 versions of jQuery included and worked around this issue by adding the `.noConflict()` method. Since I can only assume this is not the case for your website, you should not include that part upon copy/paste.
If you did, however, you disabled all previous references `$` in the "custom file" script. That would explain how the "custom file" script stopped working.

Some food for thought:

```
// when all HTML is loaded on the page
// once the DOM is ready (short version)
$(function() {
    // make sure these elements are exeactly selected as intended by using a developer toolbar (usually key F12)
    var win = $(window),
        testimonials = $('.testimonials'),
        home = $('.home'),
        sitebrand = home.find('.siteBrand'),
        navbar = home.find('.x-navbar'),
        navwrap = home.find('.x-nav-wrap.desktop'),
        anchor = navwrap.find('.x-nav > li > a');

    // start initialising other libraries ...
    testimonials.bxSlider();

    // ... or add events
    sitebrand.click(function(){
        navbar.toggleClass('x-navbarOpen').addClass('ani');
        navwrap.toggleClass('siteBrandOpen').addClass("ani");
        anchor.toggleClass('menuOpen').addClass('ani');
    });

    win.scroll(function() {    
        navbar.toggleClass('x-navbar-fixed-top', win.scrollTop() >= 750);
    });
});
```